# Link a custom column to SharePoint List items

Tags: sharepoint, custom-lists

Status: I have a custom list, and a custom column.

Problem: SharePoint lists has a built-in column called "Title". When you create a new item in the list, the item "Title" column is by default linked to the item with edit menu. I am trying to use this linkage by linking a custom column to the item. I want to disregard the built-in "Title" column and have my own custom column (i.e: "Issue") linked to the item.

I've looked around and I found this solution:

To link the Item to a specific column/field, you need to open the list in SharePoint Designer and edit the view AllItems.aspx in Advanced Mode, then look for the "ViewFields" tags and add LinkToItem=”TRUE” at the end of the column name tag like:
FieldRef Name="My Column" LinkToItem="TRUE"

Sadly however, the suggested solution above didn't work for me even though it worked for some (including the author). I followed it to the letter, and tried it on a different columns and content types. But it did not work. It would never link.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of your "Issue" column? You could simply rename "Title" to "Issue" ?!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SP 2013?
If this is the case the you shlould use "linkToItem" (small l).
I hope this works.

Best regards
Leandro.